# Data Type mismatch error when using function in SQL Statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function which gives Levenshtein Distance used for fuzzy search of a field.

```
Option Compare Database

' Levenshtein3 tweaked for UTLIMATE speed and CORRECT results
' Solution based on Longs
' Intermediate arrays holding Asc()make difference
' even Fixed length Arrays have impact on speed (small indeed)
' Levenshtein version 3 will return correct percentage
'
Function Levenshtein(ByVal string1 As String, ByVal string2 As String) As Long
1
Dim i As Long, j As Long, string1_length As Long, string2_length As Long
Dim distance(0 To 60, 0 To 50) As Long, smStr1(1 To 60) As Long, smStr2(1 To 50) As Long
Dim min1 As Long, min2 As Long, min3 As Long, minmin As Long, MaxL As Long

string1_length = Len(string1):  string2_length = Len(string2)

distance(0, 0) = 0
For i = 1 To string1_length:    distance(i, 0) = i: smStr1(i) = Asc(LCase(Mid$(string1, i, 1))): Next
For j = 1 To string2_length:    distance(0, j) = j: smStr2(j) = Asc(LCase(Mid$(string2, j, 1))): Next
For i = 1 To string1_length
    For j = 1 To string2_length
        If smStr1(i) = smStr2(j) Then
            distance(i, j) = distance(i - 1, j - 1)
        Else
            min1 = distance(i - 1, j) + 1
            min2 = distance(i, j - 1) + 1
            min3 = distance(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                If min2 < min3 Then minmin = min2 Else minmin = min3
            Else
                If min1 < min3 Then minmin = min1 Else minmin = min3
            End If
            distance(i, j) = minmin
        End If
    Next
Next

' Levenshtein3 will properly return a percent match (100%=exact) based on similarities and Lengths etc...
MaxL = string1_length: If string2_length > MaxL Then MaxL = string2_length
Levenshtein = 100 - CLng((distance(string1_length, string2_length) * 100) / MaxL)

End Function
```

When I try to write a SQL statement like the one below, I get a datatype mismatch error:

```
strSQL_1 = "SELECT * FROM Location_Table ORDER BY (Levenshtein([Short_Desc],'Search String')) DESC;"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL_1)
```

Where Short_Desc is a column in the Location_Table with Short Text datatype.

Using Debug.Print strSQL_1, this is what's shown in the immediate window:

```
SELECT * FROM Location_Table ORDER BY Levenshtein(Short_Desc,'Search String') DESC;
```

Comment: Have you tested the function to see it doesn't throw any errors? If yes, then probably the `Short_Desc` field has a null value somewhere and the function's string parameter cannot handle it. Try changing the first parameter to Variant and see if this helps. You will need to handle null values in the function through if that's the case.

Comment: ^verified, this is most certainly the answer.

Comment: Yup, personally I prefer wrapper functions, a short function that takes the same inputs but as variants, checks if any are null, if so return null, else run the original function and return its results. You can even create a generic wrapper that takes the function name and a `ParamArray` to allow typed functions, but skip them if any inputs are null